# Cannot change cr3 register to point to a new pml4 direction using pure64

Tags: c, x86, operating-system, virtual-memory

I've been trying for hours to change the direction stored at the `CR3` register, replacing the one loaded by Pure64 with a new one loaded by me.

What I'm doing is I'm taking a 4 KiB page from a direction above the 8 Mib of memory, in order to ensure I will not tread any kernel, userland, nor Pure64 module, and using it as a new direction for the PML4.
I load the new PML4 with the things I need, but when I execute the line

```
mov cr3,rdi
```

where `rdi` stores the new PML4 direction, then qemu keeps restarting itself infinitely.

Now, if I hardcode the Pure64 PML4 direction (`0x2008`) and do the same operations than before, there is no problem when calling the instruction

```
mov cr3,rdi
```

and the operating system executes correctly.

Could it be that this happens because Pure64 still needs to use the table loaded at the `CR3` register?

Here I leave the code where I load my pml4 direction: 
(Note that there are lines commented that  I've been using for debugging purpose.)

```
/* Ideas and Code extracted and modified from Wyrm OS.
Project Repository: https://bitbucket.org/RowDaBoat/wyrm/wiki/Home */

#include <virtualMemoryManager.h>
#include <mem.h>
#include <libc.h>
#include <terminal.h>
#include <own_cpu.h>

static const uint32_t presentBit = 0;
static const uint32_t writeBit = 1;
static const uint32_t userBit = 2;
static const uint32_t pageWriteThroughBit = 3;
static const uint32_t pageCacheDisableBit = 4;
static const uint32_t accessedBit = 5;
static const uint32_t dirtyBit = 6;
static const uint32_t pageSizeBit = 7;
static const uint32_t globalBit = 8;
static const uint32_t pageAttributeTableBit = 12;
static const uint32_t addressBit = 30;
static const uint64_t addressMask4KiB = 0x0000000FFFFFFFFF000;
static const uint64_t addressMask2MiB = 0x0000000FFFFFFE00000;
static const uint64_t addressMask1GiB = 0x0000000FFFFC0000000;
static const uint32_t executeDisableBit = 63;
// static const uint64_t pageSize = 4092; /* no entiendo xqq setea este tamaño de página */

static inline void setBit(uint64_t * bits, uint32_t n, bool value) {
    if (value)
        *bits |= (1 << n);
    else
        *bits &= ~(1 << n);
}

static inline bool getBit(uint64_t bits, uint32_t n) {
    return bits & (1 << n);
}

static PageTableEntry* createTable() {
    PageTableEntry * table = (PageTableEntry*) mt_mem_alloc(1);
    memset(table, 0, PAGESIZE); /* defined at libc.h */
    return table;
}

static inline PageTableEntry * clear(PageTableEntry * page) {
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < PAGESIZE / sizeof(PageTableEntry); i++)
        page[i].contents = 0;

    return page;
}

int initializeVirtualMemory()
{

    PageTableEntry * pml4 = createTable();

    /* +++xdebug */
    if (pml4 == NULL) {
        print("\nCANNOT SET PML4.\n");
        return false;
    }

    PageTableEntry * pageDirectoryPointerTable = createTable();

    /* +++xdebug */
    if (pml4 == NULL) {
        print("\nCANNOT SET PML4.\n");
        return false;
    }

    /* +++xdebug */
//  pml4 = 0x00002000;
//  pml4 = 0;
    pml4 = 0x00804008;
//  pml4 = (uint64_t pml4) & 0x8;


    //Set up the pml4, this table will be used by all mappings, kernel and user
    PageTableEntry *currentEntry = &(pml4[0]);

    print("\ncurrentEntry: ");
    printHex(pml4);
    println();

    /* +++xdebug */
    print("\nAntes de setar Presente: ");
    printHex(currentEntry->contents);
    //printInt(PageTableEntry_getPresent(currentEntry));

    PageTableEntry_setPresent(currentEntry, false);
    PageTableEntry_setWritable(currentEntry, false);
    PageTableEntry_setUser(currentEntry, false);
    PageTableEntry_setPageWriteThrough(currentEntry, true);
    PageTableEntry_setPageCacheDisable(currentEntry, false);
    PageTableEntry_setAccessed(currentEntry, false);
    PageTableEntry_setPageSize(currentEntry, false);
    PageTableEntry_setExecuteDisable(currentEntry, false);
    PageTableEntry_set4KiBPageAddress(currentEntry, pageDirectoryPointerTable);

    print("\nDespues de setar Presente: ");
    printHex(currentEntry->contents);
    //printInt(PageTableEntry_getPresent(currentEntry));


    char * page1GiB = (char*)0x0;

    //Identity map first 512 GiB (that should be all memory)
    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++, page1GiB += oneGiB) {

        currentEntry = &(pageDirectoryPointerTable[i]);
        PageTableEntry_setPresent(currentEntry, true);
        PageTableEntry_setWritable(currentEntry, true);
        PageTableEntry_setUser(currentEntry, true);
        PageTableEntry_setPageWriteThrough(currentEntry, false);
        PageTableEntry_setPageCacheDisable(currentEntry, false);
        PageTableEntry_setAccessed(currentEntry, false);
        PageTableEntry_setPageSize(currentEntry, true);
        PageTableEntry_set1GiBPageAddress(currentEntry, page1GiB);

        /* +++xdebug */
        if (i < 5) {
            print("\nPage Start at: ");
            printHex(currentEntry->contents);
            println();
        }
    }

    //Update CR3 with the new mapping
    _writeCR3((uint64_t)pml4);

    return true;
}

PageTableEntry * PageTableEntry_setPresent(PageTableEntry * entry, bool value) {
    setBit(&(entry->contents), presentBit, value);
    return entry;
}

PageTableEntry * PageTableEntry_setWritable(PageTableEntry * entry, bool value) {
    setBit(&(entry->contents), writeBit, value);
    return entry;
}

PageTableEntry * PageTableEntry_setUser(PageTableEntry * entry, bool value) {
    setBit(&(entry->contents), userBit, value);
    return entry;
}

PageTableEntry * PageTableEntry_setPageWriteThrough(PageTableEntry * entry, bool value) {
    setBit(&(entry->contents), pageWriteThroughBit, value);
    return entry;
}

PageTableEntry * PageTableEntry_setPageCacheDisable(PageTableEntry * entry, bool value) {
    setBit(&(entry->contents), pageCacheDisableBit, value);
    return entry;
}

PageTableEntry * PageTableEntry_setAccessed(PageTableEntry * entry, bool value) {
    setBit(&(entry->contents), accessedBit, value);
    return entry;
}

PageTableEntry * PageTableEntry_setDirty(PageTableEntry * entry, bool value) {
    setBit(&(entry->contents), dirtyBit, value);
    return entry;
}

PageTableEntry * PageTableEntry_setPageSize(PageTableEntry * entry, bool value) {
    setBit(&(entry->contents), pageSizeBit, value);
    return entry;
}

PageTableEntry * PageTableEntry_setGlobal(PageTableEntry * entry, bool value) {
    setBit(&(entry->contents), globalBit, value);
    return entry;
}

PageTableEntry * PageTableEntry_setPageAttribueTable(PageTableEntry * entry, bool value) {
    setBit(&(entry->contents), pageAttributeTableBit, value);
    return entry;
}

PageTableEntry * PageTableEntry_set4KiBPageAddress(PageTableEntry * entry, void * address) {
    entry->contents = ((uint64_t)address & addressMask4KiB) | (entry->contents & ~addressMask4KiB);
    return entry;
}

PageTableEntry * PageTableEntry_set2MiBPageAddress(PageTableEntry * entry, void * address) {
    entry->contents = ((uint64_t)address & addressMask2MiB) | (entry->contents & ~addressMask2MiB);
    return entry;
}

PageTableEntry * PageTableEntry_set1GiBPageAddress(PageTableEntry * entry, void * address) {
    entry->contents = ((uint64_t)address & addressMask1GiB) | (entry->contents & ~addressMask1GiB);
    return entry;
}

PageTableEntry * PageTableEntry_setExecuteDisable(PageTableEntry * entry, bool value) {
    setBit(&(entry->contents), executeDisableBit, value);
    return entry;
}

bool PageTableEntry_getPresent(PageTableEntry * entry) {
    return getBit(entry->contents, presentBit);
}

bool PageTableEntry_getWritable(PageTableEntry * entry) {
    return getBit(entry->contents, writeBit);
}

bool PageTableEntry_getUser(PageTableEntry * entry) {
    return getBit(entry->contents, userBit);
}

bool PageTableEntry_getPageWriteThrough(PageTableEntry * entry) {
    return getBit(entry->contents, pageWriteThroughBit);
}

bool PageTableEntry_getPageCacheDisable(PageTableEntry * entry) {
    return getBit(entry->contents, pageCacheDisableBit);
}

bool PageTableEntry_getAccessed(PageTableEntry * entry) {
    return getBit(entry->contents, accessedBit);
}

bool PageTableEntry_getDirty(PageTableEntry * entry) {
    return getBit(entry->contents, dirtyBit);
}

bool PageTableEntry_getPageSize(PageTableEntry * entry) {
    return getBit(entry->contents, pageSizeBit);
}

bool PageTableEntry_getGlobal(PageTableEntry * entry) {
    return getBit(entry->contents, globalBit);
}

bool PageTableEntry_getPageAttribueTable(PageTableEntry * entry) {
    return getBit(entry->contents, pageAttributeTableBit);
}

void * PageTableEntry_get4KiBPageAddress(PageTableEntry * entry) {
    return (void*)(entry->contents & addressMask4KiB);
}

void * PageTableEntry_get2MiBPageAddress(PageTableEntry * entry) {
    return (void*)(entry->contents & addressMask2MiB);
}

void * PageTableEntry_get1GiBPageAddress(PageTableEntry * entry) {
    return (void*)(entry->contents & addressMask1GiB);
}

bool PageTableEntry_getExecuteDisable(PageTableEntry * entry) {
    return getBit(entry->contents, executeDisableBit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was trying to map 1GB of physical memory directly, and qemu 2.0.0.0 was not prepared for that.
What I had to do was installing qemu 2.4.0.1 and run the VM with kvm disabled.

I hope that no one else has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Is %rdi correct? 
Bit[39~47] is the index of the pml4 table, 
and the bit [12~51] of cr3 stores the first address of the pml4 table.
```